# Populate nodes with XML data via XSLT

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I have a Drupal 6 website that needs to populate a page with data from an XML feed.  We are considering using XSLT to transform the data into an appropriate format, however in searching the internet for ideas I haven't come up with much.

So far I've found [CCK XSLT](http://drupal.org/project/cck_xslt), which doesn't seem to have much documentation behind it, and [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services), which seems to interact only with an XML-RPC server (we would simply be pulling a feed itself, not interacting with a server).

Is there a good way to go about doing this?

(Also, I don't have enough rep to create an XSLT tag.  If some kind user would like to retag for me, I'd appreciate it)

Comment: Do you need to use XSLT to store the data in the node, or store the XML in the node and use XSLT for the output only?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure.  I have a link to an XML feed that I need to display.  How it gets displayed is up in the air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (though probably not the best), is to do something like:

```
// http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7

function mymodule_permission ()
{
    return array(
        "view mypage" => array(
            "title" => t("View My Page"), 
            "description" => t("View My Page"),
        ),
    );
}

// http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

function mymodule_menu ()
{
    $items = array();

    $items["mymodule_mypage"] = array(
        "title" => "My Page",
        "page callback" => "_mymodule_generate",
        "access arguments" => array("view mypage"),
        "type" => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function _mymodule_generate ()
{
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');

    drupal_add_css("{$path}/mymodule.css", array(
        "type" => "file",
    ));

    $xsl = new DOMDocument();
    $xsl->load("{$path}/mymodule.xsl");

    $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load("{$path}/mymodule.xml");

    return (string) $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
}
```

This is stripped down code I have taken from a custom module I have for displaying a resume maintained in XML format.

Comment: Looks nice.  Would this dynamically grab the XML feed each time, or pull it in once into a new node?

Comment: This does it each time.  If you are interested in new nodes, then there is a different approach I can write up.

Comment: I think at present dynamic should be sufficient.  I appreciate it!

Comment: Just finished the implementation...working great...thanks!!